# Do gods feel uncomfortable when they approach human bodies?

Tags: vedas, gods, body, human

I heard from [this](https://youtu.be/G7yVS476BC4?list=PLBkpSRocHOO3PcaT9Pe2HqcXFSpUxGbdu&t=428) video that gods does not like to stay near human bodies and they feel uncomfortable to stay with in or nearer to human bodies?

Which slokhas of which vedic scripture tells this?

Comment: gods stay inside the susumna in all of us

Comment: Can you pls. let us know from where you came to know about this.

Comment: In Telugu pravachanam @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @hanugm Ok , the sources provided by OP actually helps  a lot in understanding context and also helps in finding answers a lot .:-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Okay, I will share it in question...

Comment: @hanugm But i suggest dropping word vomitting and insted use  word uneasy because then it will be difficult to find this exact  mention.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Edited and kept video link with particular time period...

Comment: Not only Samaveda Shanmukha Sharma, I also heard it from HH Chinna Jeeyar Swami. It definitely has a scriptural basis if multiple great personalities are saying.

Comment: we have prachitta mantra to expeciate the sin of coming near saligrama sila.. we need to recite in order to go near saligrama sila.. just like any birds like piegeon or fish or animal smell we dislike the human body by nature have unbearable odour to devathas who reside inside saligrama sila

Comment: Generally your questions are seriously good from what I observe and this is an excellent. Say for example a periyava or siddha or a rishi whose aura has expanded out of purity will generally find discomfort when someone with extreme tamasic bad karmas enter their aura. Hence we are asked to stay away from them in a distance so that we do not enter their aura